# How to determine a job's place in a PBS queue?

Tags: bash, job-scheduling, pbs

I'm working with a computation cluster that uses PBS/Torque for job scheduling. The queue can be pretty long at times, for example, I now have a few jobs submitted in a queue of over 800 (as reported by `showq` which shows a full list of jobs, but as far as I am aware these aren't necessarily in the order of execution).

I would like to find out where in the queue my jobs are located; how many will be processed before mine? I would like to get some output like: `Job <id>: 417/862`. This way I would have at least some indication of progress and waiting time. However, I have not been able to find out how to do this. Can it be done, and how?

Comment: I haven't used PBS/Torque in a while, but I'd probably write a script to process the output of `showq` or `qstat` (`showq` is actually a Maui command). (I'd use Perl myself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if I could count on it that queued jobs would be executed in the order presented by `showq`, but after some more research, it certainly looks like it.

The queue printed by `showq` has the following format:

```
ACTIVE JOBS--------
[table headers]
[listing of active jobs]
IDLE JOBS--------
[table headers]
[listing of idle jobs]
BLOCKED JOBS----------
[table headers]
[listing of blocked jobs]
```

Based on this format, I came up with the following bash script to find a job's place in the idle section of the queue, given the job's id:

```
job=$1

idlestart=`showq | grep "IDLE JOBS" -n | cut -d: -f1`

jobline=`showq | grep -n $job | cut -d: -f1`
place=`expr $jobline - $idlestart - 2`

echo "Idle Jobs section starts at line $idlestart"
echo "Job $job at line $jobline"
echo "Place in queue: $place"
```

Example output:

```
$ ./placeinq 6565618 

Idle Jobs section starts at line 343
Job 6565618 at line 387
Place in queue: 42
```